# How do I return rows where there is more than one type?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data:

```
id         user_id         typecode     
-----------------------------------
10         123             'TypeA'
11         123             'TypeB'
12         124             'TypeA'
13         124             'TypeA'
14         125             'TypeA'
15         125             'TypeB'
16         125             'TypeB'
17         125             'TypeA'
```

I need a query that will return user_ids for users that have more than 1 'TYPEA' and/or more than 1 'TypeB'. (124, 125)

This is using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: to the others that have answered, he's not looking for someone with multiple typecodes, he's looking for multiple instances of one typecode for a given person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table WHERE typecode = 'TypeA' OR typecode = 'TypeB' 
   GROUP BY user_id, typecode HAVING COUNT(typecode) > 1
```

I edited the query to take int to account that only TypeA or TypeB are of interest. Bum not exactly sure about this. This might return user two tiems if it hase 2 TypeA and 2 TypeB i.e.

Comment: again, does not work, because even with only `typeA` and `typeB`, this query returns the user `123`, which is not what the OP asked

Comment: -1 This is bringing user_id 123, which should not be considered

Comment: My bad, i attempted to fix it, but im not sure about results, it need a bit more adjusting to not return same user id twice, that is for sure. well and i hope theres nothing more wrong with it:).

Comment: Still, you should have a distinct there, since 125 is coming twice. Test, test, test...

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use case for the `union` clause.

The query below returns all users ids that have more than 1 `TypeA`
plus all users ids that have more than 1 `TypeB`.

```
-- all user_ids that have more than one TypeA
select user_id
  from yourTable
 where typecode = 'TypeA'
 group by user_id
having count(*) > 1
 union
-- all user_ids that have more than one TypeB
select user_id
  from yourTable
 where typecode = 'TypeB'
 group by user_id
having count(*) > 1
```

This query satisfies your `and/or` requirement, ie, it selects:

- all users with more than 1 typeA or
- all users with more than 1 typeB or
- all users with more than 1 typeA and more
  than 1 typeB

The beauty of `union` is that there is no need make a `select distinct user_id`, since `union` merges the result sets into unique values

Comment: +1 Although it will not work in the presence of a TypeC, your answer is the only one that works!

Comment: Should work with other typecode values. I am simply excluding them in the `where` clause

Comment: OP only asked for TypeA and TypeB. So, there is no need to even consider other types. Plus, this query still works even if there are other types present. Example: user 150 has two typeA records and one TypeC. Such user gets selected because has more than 1 typeA and that's an enough condition, no need to even bother with other types

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
    (
        SELECT user_id, 
            SUM(CASE typecode WHEN  'TypeA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TypeACount,
            SUM(CASE typecode WHEN  'TypeB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TypeBCount
            FROM <YOUR-TABLE> a
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) a
WHERE a.TypeACount > 1  OR  a.TypeBCount > 1
```

Comment: -1 This is bringing user_id 123, which should not be considered

Comment: Also, it doesn't even run, lose the `,` after TypeBCount

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id
from YourTable
group by user_id
having count(case typecode when 'TypeA' then 1 end) > 1 or
       count(case typecode when 'TypeB' then 1 end) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id  
FROM users  
GROUP BY user_id, typecode  
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Comment: -1 That will include user 123, which specifically is not what OP asked

Comment: You are right. Can you edit your answer so that I can revote?

Comment: +1 Also, I have to point out that your solution works for multiple types other than A and B

Comment: Will not work. Imagine user 123 has 1 TypeA, 1 TypeB and 2 TypeC. Such user gets selected and OP does not want that. Read the question again

Answer (score -1):

something like this maybe:

```
select user_id, count(typecode) as t_count
group by user_id
where t_count > 1
```

Comment: you normally can't access a field alias in the where clause because it's evaluated first

Comment: Iirc t_count being function column does not belong in where, it should go int having clause.

Comment: yeah it should be in the having clause, a bit tired here :(